# SSIS Export Text in Email

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-mail

We are receiving emails from this SSIS package and I need to edit the text that is in **The EMAIL** and not the data exports themselves.  I have checked the stored procedures that produce the report code, I have checked the job but that just calls the SSIS package and I have looked everywhere I can think to look but I don't see where the text in the email is coming from.

Anyone have a similar setup where they set up an SSIS package and had the results as attachments to an email?  I'm not really sure where the code would be to change it.  The Email currently says something in the body like: "Here's the report for the  previous week".

Any help would be much appreciated as I just can't find where that is pulling from so I can change it.

Comment: It is pretty normal setup, but you need to share more about your configuration and code. Please start with at least screenshot of SSIS package.

Comment: The `send mail` process is part of the SSIS Control Flow.  Do you see anything in your Control Flow for the SSIS package?